# Connect Weblogic queues from TIBCO BW

Tags: weblogic, message-queue, tibco

I have created following in Weblogic :
MyJMSServer
Persistent Store:
Target:domain
Current Server:domain

Created TestModule having:
ConnectionFactory
Type:Connection Factory
JNDI Name:JNDIConnectionFactory
Subdeployment:TestSubdeployment
Targets:MyJMSServer

Queue
Type:Queue
JNDI Name:JNDIQueue
Subdeployment:TestSubdeployment
Targets:MyJMSServer

I tested the cofiguration and connection. Both successful via TIBCO BW. But when I run it I am always getting this error - "[JMSExceptions:045102]A destination of name "Queue" was not found on WLS server "domain"."

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying the fully qualified queue name in the destination. So it should like like :
<>.<>

OR

Try adding ./ before your destination name, so that the destination name reads as : ./<>

Noel

Answer (score 0):

If you configured the connection as JNDI in BW, then destination name should be the jndi queue name on the remote server. In your example, change queue name to JNDIQueue and try it.